# Eclipse Android - where should i create .java files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file

i'm new development android apps in Eclipse.

I have to connect simple app to oracle database. I got a .java class which do that work, but i don't know where put it in the android project. (**SRC** folder? **GEN** folder?)

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sources in in the src folder, which stand for sources. I would recommend that you intall [the Eclipse ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

then create a new android project, that will set up the base files for you, then you can continue with developing.

Comment: I installed it. Thank you dude!

Answer (score 0):

src folder, gen folder is generated by the Android plugin.